# MVC C# - user creates dates from specific time zone

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

In my program I have a create screen where the user will enter a new start and end date/time. The user has a profile that specifies the time zone they want to work in. I don't want this to be relative to their local time zone.

What I want to do is take that start and end date/time that the user enters and convert it to UTC based on their user profile settings time zone. So if the user's profile is set to Eastern Standard Time and they specific the start date 1/8/16 12:00, I want that to convert from EST to UTC. I don't want the date "1/8/16 12:00" to be the system's date or their local time. I can't seem to figure out how to define "1/8/16 12:00" as EST when the conversion occurs to UTC from the user's input.

Does that make sense? Let me know if you need more info/examples.

Comment: Couldn't you store the offset as part of the timezone preference you are selecting? Also, beware of Daylight Savings Time that can occur and mess this up a bit.

Comment: Do it in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on the user's browser. You can easily get the date's UTC value there then post it to your server-side app.

Comment: @Jasen: That doesn't seem to solve the problem of applying the application timezone setting, not the OS (user) timezone.  (Just, now you get the client OS timezone instead of the server OS timezone)

Answer (score 0):

You can Save all dates in your database/nosql database/file /etc using [UTC format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx), it could be either this 2 between several ways to do it:

```
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToUniversalTime());
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date1))
```

do the query in the server and send the date in UTC format you can render it to the client in their specific timezone by formatting it using javascript, there are several libraries that can help you to do that one at the top of my head is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)  which could be a little bit of an overkill but it may be helpful in other scenarios where you could need to modify dates.

Take a look to this [small example](https://gist.github.com/fntneves/c791939bd71df4d6b479) just as a reference, which is going to display something like "2 days ago", that looks more human and more readable.

Anyway that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could always store date as UTC in database by converting regardless what user's timezone is and as you already have user's timezone info you can again convert it from UTC to user's actual timezone while displaying it to the user if you want to.
So to store in database,

```
DateTime userStartDate = new DateTime(2016, 8, 16, 12, 0, 0);
DateTime utcStartDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(userStartDate);
```

Then for outputting from database,

```
DateTime actualStartDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcStartDate, destinationTimeZone);
```